# How to turn off SSL Verification in Bot Framework using Cosmos DB emulator

Tags: botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the CosmosDB Emulator to try and develop a Bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework  using Azure Functions locally in Typescript. Whenever the bot tries to connect to the emulator, I receive the following -

**Error: Failed to initialize azure table client. Error: Error: Error Code: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT Error Body: undefined**

Any idea how can I turn off SSL in the emulator?

Thanks,
Pranav

Answer (score 0):

There may be two issues preventing you from using the Emulator:

- The Emulator does not currently Table API
- The Emulator requires SSL

We have a release coming up that will add support for the full set of APIs supported by Cosmos DB on cloud. It is available today in limited preview form. Let me know, if you'd like to give it a try.

Comment: Yes please. I would like to give it a try. Please let me know how to contact you. Just FYI, I am using this guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-cosmosdb?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#install-botbuilder-azure-module

It also seems that not all classes are exported by this module for CosmosDB. As per the guide, I am using the CosmosDB API and not the table API.